# Appium Connection closed interrupting the session

Tags: server, appium

I run tests using appium, but the connection gets closed unexpectedly interrupting all the tests leading them to fail.

Please check the screenshot of the logs[image: Appium Logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium beta has its fix for MacOs. Install the appium beta version using:

```
npm install -g appium@beta
```

Comment: Sweet, Appreciate your response.. I did the above step and it looks good.. Hoping that it will not happen again.